# Inject dependencies in Flask blueprint

Tags: python, flask, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject dependencies to a flask blueprint:

blueprints.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, Response
from dependency_injector.wiring import inject, Provide
from container import Container
from controllers import ServiceController

bp = Blueprint("event", __name__)


@bp.route("/event", methods=["GET"])
@inject
def handle_event(service_controller: ServiceController = Provide[Container.service_controller]) -> Response:
    service_controller.handle_event()
    return Response("OK")
```

I setup a container with dependencies for `ServiceController`:

container.py

```
from dependency_injector import containers, providers
from controllers import ServiceController


class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    service_controller = providers.Singleton(ServiceController)
```

and wire this to the blueprint:

wiring.py

```
from container import Container
from blueprints import bp

Container().wire(modules=[bp])
```

controller for now has an empty constructor:

controllers.py

```
class ServiceController:
    def handle_event(self):
        print("event arrived.")
```

and flask initialization:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from blueprints import bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

after running above code and requesting the `/event` endpoint I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Provide' object has no attribute 'handle_event'
```

What am I missing here?

I've referenced this documentation:
https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/examples/flask-blueprints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gonna need to use the `.init_app()` method for the container to the `Flask` App.

First create a new function `init_app` in `wiring.py`

```
from container import Container
import blueprints

container = Container()

def init_app():
    container.wire(modules=[blueprints])  # Wire the container to the blueprint, not the app
```

then import and use `init_app()` function in `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from blueprints import bp
from wiring import init_app

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp)
init_app()  # Add this line

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

then in `blueprints.py` move the `@inject` decorator

```
from flask import Blueprint, Response
from dependency_injector.wiring import inject, Provide  # Import Provide from wiring
from container import Container
from controllers import ServiceController

bp = Blueprint("event", __name__)   

@bp.route("/event", methods=["GET"])
@inject  # Move this below the route decorator
def handle_event(service_controller: ServiceController = Provide[Container.service_controller]) -> Response:
    service_controller.handle_event()
    return Response("OK")
```

Comment: alright, so in this case the module is not the blueprint but whole Flask application itself. However, when I've followed your steps I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute '__name__'`

Comment: OK, I see now - I've added a suggestion to your answer.  Blueprint should be wired (not bp from blueprint).