# How to pass an object to multiple Flask blueprints

Tags: flask

I have a DB class that uses a DB connection pool, and all SQLs are executed via it. I was instantiating directly in the blueprint as I always had just one. Now I want to split logically my routes into more than 1 blueprint files, I need to initialize the DB class in the app level to share the same one connection pool across them.

I tried adding it to `app.config` and accessing it via `current_app.config` and seems to do the trick:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__,
                static_url_path='',
                static_folder='static')

    app.config["dbobj"] = db(CONFIG)

    return app
```

But is there another better alternative to this? How to inject an object to the blueprints?

Comment: Did you consider using `flask_sqlalchemy` and follow it's usual way of initializing `db` for the application?

Comment: I mean e.g. `flask_sqlalchemy` uses `app.extensions` which seems to be more suitable than `app.config`.

Comment: @Dmitry i dont want to use sqlalchemy. But i will do give it a try with the `app.extensions`. For my problem itself, i did find this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75996750/inject-dependencies-in-flask-blueprint), but pretty hard (and overkill perhaps for my case?) to understand.

Comment: @Dmitry i took a look at flask-login and seems attaching my class to `current_app` was 2 min job. for anyone interesting, take a look at [init_app function](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.LoginManager.init_app) of that extension

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is quite short, I may not have fully understood what you mean, but you can simply add your blueprints directly to the app, there is also a separate function for that.

You can find the documentation here: https://realpython.com/flask-blueprint/

And it would work like this:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

example_blueprint = Blueprint('example_blueprint', __name__)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(example_blueprint)
```

If you want to save an object in a blueprint, you can simply do this before the first request with the ["g" object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/#storing-data).

You can do it like this:

```
my_blueprint = Blueprint('my_blueprint', __name__)

@my_blueprint.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = ...
```

Comment: This is what i do to register the blueprints to Flask, this alone doesnt tackle passing an object to the blueprints for consuming its methods.

Comment: I edited my answer, but if you want to store something in a blueprint you can do it with g object.